# Difference between two time resulting an error

Tags: php, time, timestamp, date-difference

I have this situation, i want to calculate the late of an employee and to get the late, i need to Subtract time to get the minute/hour late of an employee.

Suppose to be.. i have this code:

```
$time = strtotime($time_in);        
$late_time = date("H:i", strtotime('+15 minutes', $time));  

if(date("H:i:s",strtotime($time_duty[0]->time)) > $late_time ) {                
        $time_difference = (date("H:i:s",strtotime($time_duty[0]->time)) - $late_time)/60;
        print_r($time_difference);          
}
```

then i've encountered error

Message: A non well formed numeric value encountered

Comment: You are subtracting non well formed numeric `H:i`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$time = strtotime($time_in);    
$datetime1 = new DateTime(date("H:i:s",strtotime($time_duty[0]->time)));
$datetime2 = new DateTime(date("H:i:s", strtotime('+15 minutes', $time)));
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 2):

You are receiving this because of this line

```
$time_difference = (date("H:i:s",strtotime($time_duty[0]->time)) - $late_time)/60;
```

As of [PHP 7.1](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/invalid_strings_in_arithmetic) you will get this notice when you try to do arithmetic operation on non well-formatted string like your date

```
 $time_difference = "2019-09-14" - "2019-09-13"; // <--- Notice as of PHP7.1
```

Why are you subtracting dates strings like this anyway ? You should calculate your differences using the rich class [DateTime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) as suggested by the earlier answer. You can also create the objects this way

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime( "@" . strtotime($time_duty[0]->time));
$datetime2 = new DateTime( "@" . strtotime('+15 minutes', $time));
```

I prefer to create DateTime objects using timestamps if I got the chance, because it will free you from the hell of timezones. Check this note from the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php)

> The $timezone parameter and the current timezone are ignored when the
>   $time parameter either is a UNIX timestamp (e.g. @946684800) or
>   specifies a timezone (e.g. 2010-01-28T15:00:00+02:00).

Comment: Nice solution, vote up. But He does calculate just a time frame, so this will not going to give any effect in real.

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco thanks mate, it's not actually a solution, I just explained the cause of the error, your answer provided **the solution**

Comment: *"so this will not going to give any effect in real"* ... I didn't get it  @SergheiLeonenco , this will work as expected, it just a different way for creating the object, once it's created you can use `->diff` as you did in your code.

Comment: I agree, your suggestion it is easy to read and works perfectly fine as well.

Comment: Why do you use `strtotime` and DateTime together?

Comment: @Dharman because here I didn't want to change his code aggressively, he used it that way , and I want the timestamp that `strtotime` outputs

Comment: Isn't `new DateTime ($time_duty[0]->time);` the same as what you have with timestamp?

Comment: @Dharman Yes. I just used to instantiate DateTime objects with timestamp because of the timezone issue I mentioned in the answer, but yeah it is the same result because `strtotime` will use the default timezone.