# In php check if an item is between a given date range

Tags: php, php-carbon

I'm suck on the logic for this, my goal is to execute if an item is with in a given date range.

I get yesterday's date and the date from 8 days ago with Carbon like so:

```
$dt = \Carbon\Carbon::yesterday();
$dtB = \Carbon\Carbon::yesterday()->subDays(8);

$today = $dt->toDateString();
$todayBack = $dtB->toDateString();
```

I then need to execute this if statement to find if the item in the database fits with in these time frames.

```
    if($orderSet->item_clicked == 'printing' && $orderSet->completed_date == $today) {
      // run some stuff here
    }
```

Currently I can execute if it's today but I would like do in between these two days.  In example.  09-20-19 - 10-09-19 in between these two dates.  Just as an example.

Comment: You can realize how to make it work by looking up at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57932302/difference-between-two-time-resulting-an-error/57932360#57932360

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco That doesn't show how to do it when using Carbon.

Comment: @Barmar - He did not mentioned this until you edited. So it was just PHP solution.

Comment: The only edit I did was to add the tag, it was in the code all the time. Don't you see `\Carbon\Carbon`?

Comment: @Barmar I see, but the `$orderSet->completed_date` returns `datetime` and `$today` same thing, that's why i was thinking that it may be not bad idea to make it work even thru plain php. But like i checked `Carbon` does have solid methods to do this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carbon has a `between()` method. Use the original carbonized dates instead of the date strings.

```
$dtCompleted = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($orderSet->completed_date);
if (if($orderSet->item_clicked == 'printing' && $dtCompleted->between($dtB, $dt)) {
    // run some stuff
}
```

See the documentation of [Comparison](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison)